# C programming code keeps crashing

Tags: c

I am writing a get input function for my C program. The code compiles successfully, but when the code runs, it crashes, with the error "main.exe stopped working." Beforehand, the code would work but it said out of range for every value. The code is provided below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MIN_T -58
#define MAX_T 41
#define MIN_WCA 2
#define MAX_WCA 50

double calculateWindChill(int temperature, int windSpeed);
double convertTemperature(double windChill_F);
void displayResults(int temperature, int windSpeed, double windChill_F, double windChill_C);
bool getInput(int *pTemperature, int *pWindSpeed);
void performCalculations(int temperature, int windSpeed, double *pWindChill_F, double *pWindChill_C);
bool withinRange(int value, int min, int max);


int main(){
    int temperature, windSpeed;
    double windChill_F, windChill_C;

  getInput(&temperature, &windSpeed);

    printf("\nPatrick Borgman");
    printf("\nProject 2");
    return 0;
} //main

bool getInput(int *pTemperature, int *pWindSpeed){
    *pTemperature = 0;
    *pWindSpeed = 0;
    bool valid = false;

    printf("Enter a value for outside temperature: ");
    if(scanf("%d", *pTemperature) == true){
        if(withinRange(*pTemperature, MIN_T, MAX_T) == true){
            printf("Enter a value for wind speed: ");
            if(scanf("%d", *pWindSpeed)){
                if(withinRange(*pWindSpeed, MIN_WCA, MAX_WCA)){
                    //printf("....");
                    valid = true;
                }
                else{
                    printf("Error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return valid;
}


bool withinRange(int value, int min, int max){
    bool inRange = true;

    if(value < min || value > max){
        printf("\nThe value is out of range.");
        inRange = false;
    }
    return inRange;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", *pTemperature)` is wrong. You scan into a pointer, not the value `0`. Also, look up how to use a debugger to get more detailed information on where the error occurs.

Comment: Turn on warnings, `-Wall`, and the problems will be revealed.

Comment: Ryan can I ask what you mean by I'm scanning into 0? I thought *pTemperature meant that I have a pointer.

Comment: Oh nvm I see I have both pointers set to 0 in the local declarations of getInput

Comment: @Patrick you should pass scanf the pointer, not the dereferenced value.